# Angular test Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, unit-testing

I am currently trying to test out view1(home.js) and in view1, I use filters and directives that I moved from the view1_test.js to the app.js level.  All of my tests use to pass and now anything referencing the filters or directives now fail their tests.  I was wondering do I need to create an app_test.js or is there a way to fix the tests to still work?  Below is an example of what I am talking about.

app.js

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'myApp.home',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.date'
]).
config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider','$locationProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
}])
.filter('upper', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return input.toUpperCase();
    };
})
```

view1.js(home.js)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.home', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    });
}])
```

view1_test.js(home_test.js)

```
'use strict';
describe('myApp.home module', function () {
    beforeEach(module('myApp.home'));
}

describe('Filter: upper', function () {
    var upperFilter;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_upperFilter_) {
        upperFilter = _upperFilter_;
    }));

    it('should be able to uppercase an entire input', function () {
        expect(upperFilter('hello')).toBe('HELLO');
        expect(upperFilter('hello world')).toBe('HELLO WORLD');
    });

});
```

While running this test.  I get this:

> Chrome 47.0.2526 (Windows 7 0.0.0) myApp.home module Filter: upper should be able to uppercase an entire input FAILED
>           Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: upperFilterProvider <- upperFilter
>           http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/unpr?p0=upperFilterProvider%20%3C-%20upperFilter
>               at C:/webroot/member_portal/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
>               at C:/webroot/member_portal/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4289:19
>               at Object.getService [as get] (C:/webroot/member_portal/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
>               at C:/webroot/member_portal/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4294:45
>               at getService (C:/webroot/member_portal/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4437:39)
>               at Object.invoke (C:/webroot/member_portal/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4469:13)
>               at Object.workFn (C:/webroot/member_portal/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2438:20)
>           Error: Declaration Location
>               at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (C:/webroot/member_portal/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2409:25)
>               at Suite. (C:/webroot/member_portal/app/home/home_test.js:766:20)
>               at Suite. (C:/webroot/member_portal/app/home/home_test.js:763:5)
>               at C:/webroot/member_portal/app/home/home_test.js:3:1
>           TypeError: upperFilter is not a function
>               at Object. (C:/webroot/member_portal/app/home/home_test.js:771:20)
>   Chrome 47.0.2526 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 54 (1 FAILED) (skipped 53) ERROR (0.327 secs / 0.005 secs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared 2 different modules for each file

app.js `-> angular.module('myApp', [ ...`

view1.js `-> angular.module('myApp.home', ['ngRoute'])`

In your `home_test.js` you should be injecting the `myApp` module instead of `myApp.home` since you moved it to that module

Comment: Could you show an example.  I tried changing beforeEach(module('myApp.home')); -> beforeEach(module('myApp'));  Also beforeEach(module('myApp.home')); -> beforeEach(module('myApp'));beforeEach(module('myApp.home')); And both of those resulted in           Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
        Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngAnimate due to:
        Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngAnimate' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it.

Comment: That error is coming up because of the dependencies in `myApp` module. Either you mock those dependencies or you isolate the filter in another module and just inject that module or you could include those dependencies in your test.